# Ionic2 angular2 http get json from external api

Tags: json, angular, laravel-5, ionic2

I am aware that this might be a noob question since I've seen more complicated stuff, but to understand the complicated I need to understand the easy stuff first.

I am trying to get the name from a JSON string from an api (laravel):

```
{"name":"Abigail","state":"CA"}
```

The code is created with a route which returns this (in laravel):

```
return response()->json([
    'name' => 'Abigail',
    'state' => 'CA'
]);
```

In ionic I got these files:

page.ts:

```
export class Page {
  constructor(public http: Http) {}
    getJson() {
      this.http.get('http://external.ip/api')
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(
          data => this.data = data
      );
    }
}
```

page.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>App</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <h3>{{data.name}}<h3>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

I know this doesn't work, but I need help to get this working.
I want to be able to add more names later on.
And after that I want to be able to post data to the api (for example add a name or change a date).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work assuming something runs getJson()( I added OnInit code to do that). Gave a quick example of a simple post request for ya too. You can subscribe to that post or leave it as is.

```
//Will need on OnInit to run getJson()
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


 export class Page implements OnInit {

  constructor(public http: Http) {}

data: any;

    getJson() {
      this.http.get('http://external.ip/api')
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(
          data => this.data = data;
      );
    }
//run getJson() at initial load
ngOnInit() {
 this.getJson();
}
     postJson(data:any) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('http://52.11.14.57:4000/api/events', JSON.stringify(data), options)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I think I made some progress, but now I get an empty white page. I changed "this.data: any;" to "data: any;". and "OnInit" to "ngOnInit" with "this.getJson". I excluded the post example for now since it was also giving errors. I've added some content to the html page but it will not be displayed.

Comment: my bad on this.data and onInit. I'll correct.

Console.log the response and data....tell me what you get

Comment: I assume you left out the @Component decorator code from your example

Comment: The weird thing is I don't get an error from ionic serve. But in phpstorm it says the following when I hover "Page" in the line: "export class Page implements OnInit {": Property abstract from interface OnInit is not implemented. Can't find a solution to this if it is a problem at all.

Comment: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Comment: @Component({
  selector: 'page',
  templateUrl: 'page.html'
})

Comment: Well it doesn't output any errors after the fixes, but I don't see any content when I open the app.

Comment: console.log the data to make sure your getting it.

Comment: After some testing and comparing with another app, I found that the problem lies within the backets {{data.name}} in page.html. What is the correct way to display the data if it's correctly fetched? Now I'm getting [object Object]. I'm excited to be so close to the solution :)

Comment: Correction*: {{data}} outputs [object Object] as text. So how could I return the name or state?

Comment: OMG I got it :D {{data?.name}} This will get the name :) Thanks a lot for your help!